# Dative case error?

Tags: dative

Sorry if I sound stupid just trying to understand as well as I can, but why does "eine Schlange hat den Frosch gefressen" take a "den" instead of "dem"? I thought den was only used for possession of plural objects and seeing as *Frosch* is a singular item this kind of confused me.

Comment: It's accusative (wen oder was?).

Answer (score 1):

It's *den* because it's the object of the sentence and is in the accusative case.

For possession of plural objects (genitive case) you would use *der*. e.g *das Zeitalter der Menschen*

Answer (score 1):

"Den" is used for plural objects in the *dative* case. This is in contrast to the masculine singular "dem."

"Den" is also used for masculine singular objects in the *accusative* case. The nominative is "Der Frosch" but since the frog is being eaten, it is the direct object in the accusative case.

You would use the *genitive* case (not the dative) for a possessive, but there is nothing "possessive" about this sentence.